# How to be able to use UI component from framework in Storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, storyboard, xcode7

I would like to use an `UIView` subclass from an external framework in my project's Storyboard. I tried with different projects but each time I can't see the class name in the custom class dropdown menu.

Is it possible to make it work?

I guess the frameworks are fine, it should be an import/linking problem.

Comment: Does it actually fail at runtime?

Comment: No, not even a warning. It just crashed when I try to use the UIVIew in my UIViewController.

Comment: Something like bad access. Now it doesn't crash and at runtime it works as expected, but I haven't changed anything, just rebuilding (I already tried rebuilding, cleaning and many other things multiple times before without result)... That's weird. The class name is still not present in the custom class dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

One thing could be that you are using a mix of swift and objective c like your project is in swift and your framework is in objective c in that case you need to add bridging header and import your .h files in it. It will work if that's the case

Comment: Wouldn't the compiling fail in that case? Anyway The project and the framework are both using Swift (2.0).